# Convergence of series for $z_n$ in the right half-plane

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ all lie in the right half-plane Re $z \geq 0$, and both series $\sum_{n=1}z_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}z_n^2$ converge; show that $\sum_{n=1}|z_n|^2$ also converges.

Can anyone provide any insight into this problem? I've thought about trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}x_n^2 + y_n^2$ converges, by using the assumptions given, specifically $\sum_{n=1}z_n \text{ converges} \implies \sum_{n=1}x_n+iy_n \text{ converges} \implies \sum_{n=1}x_n \text{and} \sum_{n=1}y_n$ converge, and $\sum_{n=1}z_n^2 \text{ converges} \implies \sum_{n=1}x_n^2+2ix_ny_n - y_n^2 \text{ converges}$, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Also, I don't see the relevance of $z_1,z_2,...z_n$ lying in the half-plane.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n =  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Re(z_n)$ converges and $x_n \geqslant 0$, also $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^2$ converges. Use

$$x^2 + y^2 = 2x^2 - (x^2-y^2).$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!